# How to design an application that can use multiple GUI libraries?

Tags: design-patterns, dynamic

I'm facing the following design problem: imagine an application that have 2 main parts, one for communication (COM) and one for the user interface (UI). Both are different libraries into different files. Now, I would like to keep UI modular, to be able updating it in the future with different libraries (i.e. GTK, Qt, WinForms, etc). 
The problem is: COM interfaces with a device, which can be different at time, and it must show a configuration view into the application settings form/window. Since every new COM implementation might be different with different configuration data, every change must be reflected into the settings form/window.

How can i keep my application modular, without being forced to redesign the whole UI every new COM implementaion?

I thought to load dynamically a COM library and a Settings library. The last one would depend directly on the current COM implementation, interfacing with its own configuration data.
If i change the COM implementation, i just have to reimplement the Settings library and let the framework loads it at runtime with COM.

This solution feels a bit tricky to me. Do you have any other suggestion?

Thank you in advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest going with a variation of [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller).  Create abstractions in both your interface and backend so that you can implement the core functionality and override specific details for each device.  This will allow you to reuse the parts of your interface and backend that are common among all cases and change only a portion depending on which device is connected.  At the same time, your UI is decoupled from your backend.

Comment: Do you suggest to keep the Configuration Form/Window into the UI implementation or into an another module, which depends directly on COM module?

Comment: @sawk Keep the UI portion with the UI implementation, and the backend functionality separate with the rest of the backend.  This way you can change the UI implementation in the future and not have to change any of the business logic.

Comment: Thank you. I've actually removed the dynamic loading part, which sounded a bit an over-kill and it made the project a bit too complex. To create a generic configuration object which could contain everything from future implementations sounded an overkill as well. Then I directly let UI depends from Core and COM implementation.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the @Floegipoky answer, I think you'll find helpful [Separated Presentation](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/SeparatedPresentation.html) by  Martin Fowler. At the heart of MVC, and the idea that was the most influential to later frameworks, is already above mentioned Separated Presentation. The idea behind it, is to make a clear division between domain objects that model our perception of the real world, and presentation objects that are the GUI elements we see on the screen. Domain objects should be completely self contained and work without reference to the presentation, they should also be able to support multiple presentations, possibly simultaneously. This approach was also an important part of the Unix culture, and continues today allowing many applications to be manipulated through both a graphical and command-line interface.